# I'm not able to do operations with phpmyadmin on server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

1. I went to Cpanel, and from there created a **user** and a **database** with the option **MySQL Databases** in Cpanel.
2. I inserted and created tables without any problem.
3. Now when I want to connect to it, with these parameters:

   $servername = "127.0.0.1";
   $username = "aa";
   $password = "aa";
   $dbname = "bb";

It says : Access denied for user 'aa'@'localhost' to database 'bb'. even though I've created the user with the option **MySQL Databases** in Cpanel.

4. I have to tell that I don't see some options like, **User Accounts**, in phpmyadmin on my server. I tried some options, for example seeing users available (SELECT User.....), but It gave me an error to, because that user didn't have privileges.

I have all kinds of access problems.

Comment: The error message should also contain `(using password: YES)`, is that the case? Otherwise you have _not_ supplied a password while trying to make the connection.

Comment: @CBroe Immediately after those for variables I have this: $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

Comment: Are you sure MySQL is running on the same host as the webserver?

Comment: is your server name correct ?

Comment: @SNTiwari I'm not sure! I've seen tutorials which say, your servername shoud be this. How should I know it is something else?

Comment: @Matt I don't know very much about this. Can you explain it simple?

Comment: @Messi.Meysam check your server name from your hosting partner account, if you are using `VPS` or `Dedicated` then `Server Name` may be different than `localhost` Or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Messi.Meysam it is probably worth raising a ticket with your host to ask them what the server should be, as it's going to vary between hosts if it's not `localhost`.

Comment: @Messi.Meysam: have you created user with correct privileges ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new User in cpanel with the option to have MySQL databases doesn't necessarily create the database user itself. Make sure you use the MySQL Database Wizard in CPanel to set up your users.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the mysql server in the same server your application is in, settings should be

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "aa";
$password = "aa";
$dbname = "bb";
```

also create the user and grant privileges to the user

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```